# Expected indented block - line continuation?

Tags: python, dictionary, indentation, line-breaks

```
solved_places = {

    'a1': False,'a2': False,'a3': False,'a4': False,'a5': False,
    'b1': False,'b2': False,'b3': False,'b4': False,'b5': False,
    'c1': False,'c2': False,'c3': False,'c4': False,'c5': False,
    'd1': False,'d2': False,'d3': False,'d4': False,'d5': False,
    'e1': False,'e2': False,'e3': False,'e4': False,'e5': False
    }
```

Getting error pointer on the second line, (b1) asking for an indentation.
(ERROR: Expected an indented Block)
Whats wrong? (no Spaces, all tabs, 1 tab = 4 Spaces...)

I've tried different Levels of indentation, Spaces, commas etc...) like this:

```
solved_places = 

    {'a1': False,'a2': False,'a3': False,'a4': False,'a5': False,
    'b1': False,'b2': False,'b3': False,'b4': False,'b5': False,
    'c1': False,'c2': False,'c3': False,'c4': False,'c5': False,
    'd1': False,'d2': False,'d3': False,'d4': False,'d5': False,
    'e1': False,'e2': False,'e3': False,'e4': False,'e5': False}
```

Comment: What is the code that is accompanying this dictionary? If you make the dictionary all on the same line do you get the same error?

Comment: The first version works just fine for me; any problem has to be due to the preceding code, or some difference between what's posted here and your actual code.  The second version is invalid, you need that unmatched `{` on the first line to keep the statement open over multiple lines.

Comment: just prior to this is a couple of lines of comments using ''' (comment) '''. It might be affecting it in some way...

Comment: ..and yes, same error even when its all one Looong line.. very strange..

Comment: Upon reviewing previous lines of code, I came across a def func(): With no content, and my editor was misleading me as to where the error was.